# Prevent prettier to move the double quote in html to new lines

Tags: html, typescript, formatting, prettier

When formatting a html file if I have a very long string bound to a property it will move the double quotes to new lines.

current behaviour:

[image: current-behaviour]

expected behaviour:

[image: expected-behaviour]

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Not prettier related but: `[foo]="'bar'"` is useless. Consider doing `foo="bar"`

Comment: try changing "printWidth": 120 setting in your prettier config

Comment: @JSEvgeny Indeed that worked and I can play around to see a good value for me. thank you.